# Rsync - What does the -b (backup) flag concretely does?

Tags: backup, rsync

I can't get my head around what the -b flag does.
According to the official documentation :

> With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as each file is transferred or deleted.

But I don't get what this means. How can you rename a file being deleted ? How is renaming files related to backups ? No files were renamed after invoking rsync with -b :

```
rsync --delete -bavh
```

And when I go through different tutorials they never really use this option, so is it really useful ?

What would be the difference between

```
rsync --delete -bavh
```

and

```
rsync --delete -avh
```

Also, it might not be useful, but my use case is the following : I want to make a backup of my desktop onto a mounted WebDAV drive. The backup will run every day at a given time automatically.

Comment: Is it supposed to be used along side with `--ignore-existing` though

Comment: Yeah, sorry I had to remove this flag anyway after experimenting but I still don't get the -b flag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of the `backup` option is to keep a copy of any over-written and/or
removed files.

It may be used with `--backup-dir` to keep these files in another directory
than the target directory.

You can additionally specify a backup suffix using the `--suffix` option
which will be appended to the file-name.
Without it, the files backed up in the specified `backup-dir` directory
will keep their original filenames.
With it, the files can be renamed and stay in the original directory
(meaning that `backup-dir` is not required).

So either `backup-dir` or `--suffix` are required when `backup` is used.

Comment: Mmmh okay that does explain things. So I suppose it is not fully compatible with the --delete flag (that I've been using) ?

Comment: The  combination of the `backup` and `delete` flags needs also either `backup-dir` or `suffix` to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  So, considering that `rsync` does backup,  `rsync --backup` does "backup of backup", which may be a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Played with this. This is what I found out.

Use the --backup and --backup-dir to create a kinda sorta incremental backup.

Say you have this code:

```
# test date with a timestamp:
date +%F_%H-%M-%S
2024-03-06_19-48-08

#
SRC=your/cooldir
DST=backups
INCDIR="${DST}/inc_$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S)"
rsync -avh --backup --backup-dir="$INCDIR" "$SRC/" "$DST/"
```

When you run this the first time, you get backups/cooldir which is a full backup (a mirror sync) of your/cooldir.

Now add a file newfile.txt to your/cooldir. Run the code again. No files were deleted or changed, so the INCDIR is not created.

Now delete your/cooldir/newfile.txt. Run the code again.
Since that file was deleted and --backup and --backup-dir were specified, you get backups/cooldir as before (a full backup) but you also get directory backups/inc_2024-03-06_19-57-23. Inside that incremental directory you get newfile.txt. It's there because it was deleted.

You can try this again by creating newfile2.txt run it, and then  on the second run, just modify newfile2.txt (don't delete it). You again get the newfile2.txt in the backups/inc_xx folder.

Now try the code but change this line:

```
INCDIR="${DST}/inc_$(date +%F)"
```

And re-run these scenarios. The first time you'll get newfile.txt in backups/inc_2024-03-06. The second time you'll have both newfile.txt and newfile2.txt in that same directory. In other words the --backup and --backup-dir isn't exactly an incremental backup. It's more of an accumulation of the last changes/deletes to files.

Finally, try this change:

```
rsync -avh --backup "$SRC/" "$DST/"
```

This time you get the changed and deleted files renamed with a tilde e.g. newfile.txt~